# View Model classes not updated in azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My site is down now as I have updated RegisterViewModel and tested it locally and it worked fine. I added a new field 'Notifications'
however after publishing to azure my site crashes with the following error:

```
'RegisterViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Notifications'
```

More details here:

```
 An unhandled exception has occurred: One or more compilation failures occurred:
      3cmgspbk.ncu(571,3721): error CS1031: Type expected
      3cmgspbk.ncu(571,3935): error CS1031: Type expected
      3cmgspbk.ncu(571,3777): error CS1061: 'RegisterViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Notifications' and no extension method 'Notifications' accepting a first argument of type 'RegisterViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
      3cmgspbk.ncu(571,3991): error CS1061: 'RegisterViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Notifications' and no extension method 'Notifications' accepting a first argument of type 'RegisterViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
```

Comment: We need more details to understand the problem. Where does the error occur? What is the stack trace? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: I have added a field to the registration form and called it Notifications. so whenever someone opens registration form this error gets logged, I have this whenever I try to create a view model in azure. Is there a way to update model class (.cs) under models folder in azure?

Comment: @NateBarbettini I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the model was updated, but some other part of the application was not. It's impossible to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: @NateBarbettini 1- Am I suppose to do any migrations if I changed RegisterViewModel? 2- Is it possible to update model classes in azure? your help is very much appreciated

Comment: I would agree with @NateBarbettini that there is some other part of the app that is probably referencing a property that has been removed. I would recommend you enable view compilation to see what is incorrect: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/compile-your-asp-net-mvc-views/

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET but it's working fine on localhost... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the dll will need to be overwritten and this can be done by making sure  that you have cleaned out the previous files if deploying to an existing application. This is how to do it in Visual Studio:

[image: The display in Microsoft Visual Studio]

In the center under FILE PUBLISH OPTIONS, please checkmark : REMOVE ADDITIONAL FILES AT DESTINATION
 
Maybe older files are interfering with the new ones!

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this issue, it was because an outdated version of my assembly was in the 'ref' folder on the Azure deployment. The app worked normally on the development machine which had no 'ref' folder. In my case the 'remove additional files at destination' was not appropriate for my setup.

Just changing the setting for MSBuild to generate reference files was not enough; I had to rename the 'ref' folder through the Kudu shell and let the redeploy generate a fresh folder.